# Im having trouble getting a prepared statement UPDATE to iterate in a loop

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The reason Ive put it in a loop is because I want to add specific data for each day of a specified month, thus the loop runs 'n' amount of times where n is the amount of days in a month. Heres my code:
    $i = 0;

```
    while ($i < $loop_count) {

        $day_prefix = $i + 1;
        if (strlen($day_prefix) == 1) {
            $day_prefix = "0" . $day_prefix; //this gives 2012-01-01 through to 2012-01-31
        }

        if ($stmt = $sql_con->prepare("UPDATE DailyBudget SET amount = ? 
                                            WHERE date=?, code=?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('isi', $budget_daily, $date_iterator . $day_prefix, $code);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

        }else
            echo "fail! </br>";

        $i++;
    }
$sql_con->close();        
}
```

Ive spent more time than I would like trying to figure this out, so some help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your primary issue is in the [where condition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). The [where condition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be updated. As an [expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/expressions.html), the component/sub conditions must be combined in the where condition through logical operators. In other words, use `AND` instead of commas (`,`)in the where clause/condition

Consider altering your code to look more like this:

```
if ($stmt = $sql_con->prepare('UPDATE DailyBudget SET amount = ? WHERE date=? AND code=?')) {
    $year = 2012;
    $month = 1;
    $days_in_month = (int) date('d',(mktime(0,0,0,$month+1,1,$year)-86400));
    $day = 1;
    while ($day <= $days_in_month) {

        $budget_daily = 15.75 - .25 * $day;
        $code = 1;

        $date = $year.'-'.str_pad($month,2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT).'-'.str_pad($day,2,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $stmt->bind_param('dsi', $budget_daily, $date, $code); 
        $stmt->execute();

        $day++; 
    }   
    $stmt->close();
}
else echo 'WARNING: There was an error with the prepare: '.$sql_con->error."\n";
$sql_con->close();
```

Comment: It works. Thank you ghbarrat. I have spent a lot of time stressing over this today, so thank you. I hope you have an excellent day.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should use `bind_value` rather than `bind_param` as you create values on the fly and prepare statements for each insert. For `bind_param` you should try something like

```
$i = 0;
$stmt = $sql_con->prepare("UPDATE DailyBudget SET amount = ? WHERE date=?, code=?");
$stmt->bind_param('isi', $budget_daily, $date_iterator_prefix, $code);
while ($i < $loop_count) {
    $day_prefix = $i + 1;
    if (strlen($day_prefix) == 1) {
        $day_prefix = "0" . $day_prefix; //this gives 2012-01-01 through to 2012-01-31
    }
    $date_iterator_prefix = $date_iterator . $day_prefix;
    $stmt->execute();

    $i++;
}
$stmt->close();               
$sql_con->close();
```

Comment: and if i was to use bind_value?

Comment: @Glenncito in your code use `bind_value` instead of `bind_param`

Comment: the code program simply ends at the prepare statement. If i comment it out, it ends at the excecute statement and if i comment that out too then the program runs though. What could this mean?

Comment: It doesnt return any errors, it just stops running at at "$stmt = $sql_con->bind_param(or bind_values)...". Ive set all sorts of echos after that point which dont excecute, this is how i Know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the benefit of prepared statement is that it's prepared once and executed many times.

So, you must **put prepare before the loop.**

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE DailyBudget SET amount = ? WHERE date=?, code=?"');
while($i < $loop_count) {
    $sth->execute(array($budget_daily, $date_iterator.$day_prefix, $code));
}
```